# dnssec-keygen key default validation / expiration time

Tags: bind, dnssec

What is the default expire time/period for a key, generated by dnssec-keygen:

If i execute:
`dnssec-keygen -a RSASHA256 -b 2048 -f KSK mydomain.com`

I get 2 files:

(Kmydomain.com.+008+21346.key)

```
; This is a key-signing key, keyid 21346, for mydomain.com.
; Created: 20151208123320 (Tue Dec 08 13:33:20 2015)
; Publish: 20151208123320 (Tue Dec 08 13:33:20 2015)
; Activate: 20151208123320 (Tue Dec 08 13:33:20 2015)
mydomain.com. IN DNSKEY 257 3 8 AwEAAfcTOQq0VoMZFTKMPsRzUlO4cUzZvHCf9sb+MMeZhfMyLOSc6j6j hKtfYOVAwxDu7hEG5pG+5V908r7EAgZfjJgBPFlz6c3xZ9Yf5FqU4vRR CAAMye/87e2J4TKoFnv6J/8Vigz21IvKGYgdsXMs5Pf8rgqPgpZjXP+D gMxezJH1dQYV3oW6zULttm1/4+yeXZrc1NIzbmS3AChwKCNtP+fcj0dt PpV8Z8lcd0EnhZWCN7KZTgs8kzRHVGNKZSJ7Mvlklt74vNXnjpwsl3LL Uxi0ucXiWd7zB3eBA92+lH13QJPZnlUGe7iGiD4HYOeFAyRQGGYzd1Gf 3xwtWyF/3h8=
```

and (Kmydomain.com.+008+21346.private)

```
Private-key-format: v1.3
Algorithm: 8 (RSASHA256)
Modulus: 9xM5CrRWgxkVMow+xHNSU7hxTNm8cJ/2xv4wx5mF8zIs5JzqPqOEq19g5UDDEO7uEQbmkb7lX3TyvsQCBl+MmAE8WXPpzfFn1h/kWpTi9FEIAAzJ7/zt7YnhMqgWe/on/xWKDPbUi8oZiB2xcyzk9/yuCo+ClmNc/4OAzF7MkfV1BhXehbrNQu22bX/j7J5dmtzU0jNuZLcAKHAoI20/59yPR20+lXxnyVx3QSeFlYI3splOCzyTNEdUY0plInsy+WSW3vi81eeOnCyXcstTGLS5xeJZ3vMHd4ED3b6UfXdAk9meVQZ7uIaIPgdg54UDJFAYZjN3UZ/fHC1bIX/eHw==
PublicExponent: AQAB
PrivateExponent: vn6qry8luIRBTKzGxC5p3jTJ3kfOO0OKQBjBwVMD7OLVrBmznUHzyzGJgpgxDcA5+xTH9r0pGjUP57c2HHXU72mcfxeYv3kN5xDFvnUmmtpTAb7af1cSlt+EqsrgMwxHhCu2OZKhg3n5v3GtXDDUBMNj6K6HL65CiJp6VpgMv8btbDMBkc+eytFmJDIJ0FdOtlWxJYzFTZ6lAcxR7sSOidP/nKz8/5GLwwU/dxdMWS5xavzJYTZjG7ZQRwkTcEGZ9/PjgSzeqOUvJt2pcQXt6mi5/ZNpcC1843JYt+N6/O0sHSmphtv7WYOl5FOBYJP66akfv1XeNaYHKDZg+A+kUQ==
Prime1: /0oPncwFldrW/Iu3HmymBk4ntelWsKJgtaEZNXe7p5KXs4w8V48t+y2bz6k89ZSdR5cpVPmXd28BHqbODgetBkKKCi+P2+3N//7EuKr4qEVT/w7BWtp6+5zBnl6nBtblxz4RuBIb6kuues6GfHfIRMngeggxduuSCpOlSRyyGlc=
Prime2: 98NOx4xaPweAgz98gxPWXEQ6uB3CzVI1NFIGN1xGhS9qSq1FRWDe2bH5RjXh9m2tDCXC/TKzBjUfe3+xNKliO+Kkr7V45jpAlAfU2M3GKJ4Yqv9zHgk4ueQAtOFx6cQNywOLUnY4ms+JkmnWVWQxuBkcFPBY+9iuGLc3NbL9DXk=
Exponent1: qsieB9+MQQMk3dCOEbF3pDI2yLCwSPxoHDoIxkcyZ9le2UPQvnbPuQB7AwJiAJyKV3FdujY7STAenKXUpXgnHU/4TvYglG3TaRXD/xKJxPCUT8ZMPf55Vcg5kzwZGy86iv8QFYcv258Du65cM/piJPq0zI6coMTZb2/0nCOxVoM=
Exponent2: D578xJAQ0JCEhcHm88y4YzDaEumtcoyQVjAlvC/RMmx+4x5xk6I76rXR5Z9YE9VuZ6mp1ZTwvJ900LCIV62mR+hOQdXLPZjGoY6s2M6Ag+cT3xQkCezC6tV5Re5A5GA8DmS20AgsIXacUeLiZJfgmp7aqmdM9PQAZgaHMJeMZOE=
Coefficient: jmEpQL+U4NCvGrucQHHwdSlNphGI86rpuyB32vBs5khx1kiVyfj06/0yP2QAXjZv9DLoKxpfDwv7VGJb9hqr98E27zhdHzSNV5mo5COR7wMcApPfPZvu7k9pwiqf+MT1eNdzS31fOIp8APpaDMCnYPiIxbtynUHeUCU/etH2oxg=
Created: 20151208123320
Publish: 20151208123320
Activate: 20151208123320
```

As i thought the key(s) have a validation time, and will automaticly be revoked after the time is up.

Is there a default value for expiration - or do i have to manually set it via the `-R` flag as descriped @ the [dnssec-keygen man page](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind/9.10.0a2/doc/arm/man.dnssec-keygen.html) ?

Or did i missunderstood something completly wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Times if you do not set them via params as descriped in the [Manual from dnssec-keygen](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind/9.9.8/doc/arm/man.dnssec-keygen.html) are:

```
Published: {Time of creation}
Activated: {Time of creation}
Revoked: Not set
Retired: Not set
Deleted: Not set
```

So if you do not set any Times on the Keys, it will be default last for ever (or until KSK will change and you HAVE to rotate the Key)

U also have the ability to change the dates later via [dnssec-settime](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind/9.9.8/doc/arm/man.dnssec-settime.html)